# Dynamic values are not getting displayed in Partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a partial view and I am getting the values in the model as well. I have written a code for displaying the values in 'foreach' but those dynamic values are not getting printed . If I give something static, its coming perfectly.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 @Html.DisplayFor(itemmodel => item.xxx)
 <p><span>rrriygouhnojn</span></p>
}
```

While debugging I am able to see the values in item.xxx

Comment: what's your `xxx` property type?

Comment: Yes. It's item.name

Comment: sorry i means what's your `xxx` property data type?

Comment: Datatype is String .

Answer (score 0):

Just write your own string Display template.

Create a `cshtml` file like:

> Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MyTemplate.cshtml

**MyTemplate.cshtml**

```
@model string
@Model
```

Use:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 @Html.DisplayFor(itemmodel => item.xxx,"MyTemplate")
}
```

**OR**

you view render but your html page not refresh second time so you have two way 1. refresh your view via `ajax` call . 2. load your data first time.Example:

**View.cshtml:**

```
@model MyModel

@{ Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewName", Model.ViewModel); }
```

Comment: Sorry this too is not helping

Comment: Does it because of partial view?

Comment: can you show your view  with how to call your partialview?

Comment: @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/PM/_HistoryViewpartial.cshtml", new List<App.Models.ViewModel.MasterData> { new App.Models.ViewModel.MasterData() });}

Comment: first it will send the null value, after that, on an action from the main view. it will bind the data and send to the partial view again  
 second time I am able to see the value while debugging it. Unfortunately its not printing.

Comment: @poc you view render but your html page not refresh second time so you have two way 1. refresh your view via `ajax` call . 2. load your data first time. see my update answer.

Comment: I am using the below given call for refreshing it  .....................

    function SubmitAction(file) {

        

        $.ajax({ url: '/PM/History' ,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {file:file}
        }).done(function() {
           
        });
    }